# Ajax with validate.js returning undefined result from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validate.js

*Hello All, I have written a one demo code to check weather the given input user is exist in the list or not using ajax and validate.js, when I'm running the code all functions are executing fine but insted of getting response message in succes function it is jumping to the error function and giving undefined response as sent form php.*

**Here is my code:**

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkUserExists", function(value, element){           
            alert("input checking");
            var inputElem = $('#hl_form :input[name="username"]'),
                data = { "username" : inputElem.val(),"check": "userCheck"},
                eReport = ''; //error report

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "services.php",
                async: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data, 
                success: function(result)
                {
                    alert(result);
                    console.log(result);
                    if (result.status !== 'true')
                    {
                      return '<p>This User is already registered.</p>';
                    }else{
                       return true;
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    //alert('ajax loading error... ... '+url + query);
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }, 'User Alread exist in the DB');
```

**My Validate.js Rules and and Message are**

**Validate Method Rule**

```
username: {             
           required: true,          
           checkUserExists:true 
}
```

**Validate.js Method Message**

```
username: {             
           required: "Please enter your Username",           
           checkUserExists: "User... already exist"  
},
```

**My Php Code (service.php)**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    class form_services{
        public $sql;
        public $returnResult = array();
        function checkUser($requestedUser) {
            $registeredUser = array('xyz', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl');
            if( in_array($requestedUser, $registeredUser) ){
               $returnResult["status"] = 'false';
            }else{
                $returnResult["status"] = 'true';               
           }             
        return $returnResult;
        }


    } //Class Ends Here

    $checkRequest  = $_POST['check'];
    $frmServices = new form_services();
    $data = '';     
    switch ( $checkRequest) {       
    case 'userCheck':   $requestedUser  = $_REQUEST['username'];
                        $data = $frmServices->checkUser( $requestedUser);
                        echo json_encode($data);
                        break;      
          default:      echo json_encode($data);
                        break;
    }
    ?>
```

**Please help me in resolving my issue, i'm getting undefined result in ajax call from php cod.**

Comment: What is the exact error message you are receiving?

Comment: Look at the Network tab in your browser's Developer Console, and check the Headers and Response tabs of the request to see what is being sent and received.

Comment: My false part is exicuting, That is  **User... already existt** and it is due to ajax is not getting result in success function.

Comment: @aynber in **headers tab** I'm getting **Status Code: 200 OK** and In **Response Tab** I'm getting **{"status":"true"}**